# WPF Drag & Drop in RightToLeft Direction

Tags: wpf, drag-and-drop, direction

Is there a bug in WPF Drag and Drop when it runs in RTL mode?
It seems it does not update the drop object area which it's FlowDirection set to RTL.
I currently using WPF 3.5 + SP1 and facing this problem, Additionally, it seems this is inherited in WPF 4.0 and also does not work properly in VS2010.
Who can providing a solution or workaroubnd ?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: have you made any process on solving this, if so please update your question

Comment: Please report it to http://connect.microsoft.com/

Answer (score 2):

The issue has been reported to [Microsoft Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/476535/drag-and-drop-in-wpf-not-working-as-expected-in-righttoleft-fllowdirection-and-calling-wrong-drop-events) and it should have been fixed in .NET 4.0.
Notice, by the way, that the problem does occur if you set `FlowDirection = "RightToLeft"` on the `Window` itself, but not if you set it on its controls (i.e. the inner `Grid`, or main `Panel`).